# How to overwrite the return address of the assembler stack with an address given by C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, coroutine, context-switch

I got a function `switchContext(void*& from, void*& to)`. It receives two stack pointers and shall change the context of a process. So if I got a coroutine A and it uses a specific function `resume()`, coroutine B shall go on working. 
Currently I have trouble getting my code to work.

I am using Nasm & GCC for compiling.

Assembler program: (`switchContext(void*& from, void*& to)`):

```
switchContext:

    ; epb = esp
    mov     ebp, esp

    ; save registers
    push    ebp
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi

    ; from <= returnadress
    ; eax <= returnadress
    mov     eax, [ebp+16] 
    mov     edx, ebp
    add     edx, 20 ; make edx point to 'from'
    ; overwrite 'from' with returnadress
    mov     [edx], eax

    ; what to do now: returnadress <= to
    ; eax <= to
    mov     eax, [ebp+24]
    mov     edx, ebp
    add     edx, 16 ; make edx point to returnadress
    ; overwrite returnadress with 'to'
    mov     [edx], eax

    pop     edi ; RSA = esp + 12
    pop     esi ; RSA = esp + 8
    pop     ebx ; RSA = esp + 4
    pop     ebp ; RSA = esp + 0

    ; use new returnadress to jump to 'to'
    ret
```

And this is the corresponding C++ class:

```cpp
extern "C" {
    void switchContext(void*& from, void*& to);
}

class Coroutine {
public:

    const char* name;
    Coroutine(void* tos = 0)
    {
        setup(tos);
    }

    void resume(Coroutine* next)
    {

        switchContext(this->sp, next->sp);
    }

    virtual void body() = 0;
    virtual void exit() = 0;

private:
    static void startup(Coroutine* obj) {
        obj->body();
        obj->exit();
    };

    void setup(void* tos) {
        if (tos == 0) {
            unsigned temp_stack[1024];
            this->sp = &temp_stack;
            return;
        }

        this->sp = &tos;
        return;
    };

    void* sp;
};
```

Currently my program simply crashes. But it only does so by overwriting the return address in assembler with the 'to'.

Where am I making a mistake in this process?

Comment: Just to make this complete could you provide a small test program that uses this class to set up a couple of coroutines. That would at least make this an [mcve] for anyone who finds this question.

Comment: I will applaud you for not using inline assembly and deciding on something more straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mov ebp,esp` is in the wrong place.  It should be after the register saves.

You're not dereferencing the references.  From an assembler point of view a C++ reference is just a pointer, so your parameters are `void **`.  Since you want to save/load the return addresses to what is pointed at, you need an extra indirection to save the value to the pointed to address.

Unrelated to this problem: Some of your address calculations using `edx` can be condensed into fewer instructions.  You could also dispense with using `ebp` and use `esp` based offsets.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. These were the crashing bugs.

Comment: But still the process does not change the context. It simply stops after calling `resume()` for the first time.

Comment: @IPodFan Your `setup` is wrong.  `&temp_stack` and `&tos` do not correspond to the stack values you need for your `switchContext`.  Another assembly function (to get this initial value) would be a help.

Comment: I may be missing something. Are you sure about not having to save EDI or ESI? Although those registers are not used by the function itself, I would think that all the non-volatile (callee preserved) registers (EBP, ESP, EBX, EDI, and ESI) would have to be preserved across the coroutine switch. My impression was that the intended use of those particular registers being pushed was to ensure the caller context could always be properly restored. The volatile registers (EAX, ECX, EDX) don't matter as they aren't expected to retain their values when `switchContext` returns.

Comment: Without saving them you could have something like EDI=1, ESI=2 then `call switchContext`. Assume another coroutine starts executing when `switchContext` returns and does EDI=3, ESI=4 and then it does `call switchContext`. If the context switches back to the original routine then `switchContext` will return with EDI=3,ESI=4 where that coroutine may be assuming they have been unmodified per the calling convention and expected them to be EDI=1, ESI=2

Comment: I also have a concern about this in the OP's code `unsigned temp_stack[1024];
            this->sp = &temp_stack;` . This is done inside `setup` so that array is created as a temporary on the stack which will go out of scope when `setup` returns. That pretty much will get clobbered later on. So saving a pointer to it won't cut it. Either put the array in the class or dynamically allocate the array (on the free-store) - the latter would be my preference.

Comment: Of course on top of that the stack will grow down from `sp`. `sp` should point at the end of the allocated stack area so the stack could grow down from there.

Comment: Both of you are right. 1. I need to assign an initial return adress to the stack, otherwise I cannot return without calling body() explicitly. 2. I need to transfer my data in the right way without overwriting it. Currently I am working on these points.